# Separable quotients of non-separable Banach spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I am reading the Functional Analysis book of Conway, one question from the book is find a closed subspace M of $l^{\infty}=l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ with the property that $l^{\infty}/M$ is separable. I have found a solution for this but here is my question :

1. Is  it true that every non-separable normed space $X$ always contains  a closed (proper) subspace $M$ such that $X/M$ is linear isometric to a separable  normed space whose  dimension is infinite ? i.e, are there a map $A$ and a separable normed space $Y$ whose  dimension is infinite, st:   $A: X/M\to Y$ which is linear, onto, and preserve the distance?

(Edit: I already have an answer for the following question
I am thinking a about $l^{\infty}$ : can it contain  a closed proper subspace M that $l^{\infty}/M$ is isometric to $l^{1}=l^{1}(\mathbb{N})$?)

Comment: By the way, something seems to be wrong with your quote from Conway

Comment: The answer is affirmative. Namely, take M as the kernel of any [non-trivial] continuous linear functional on X.

Comment: In your first question, about merely getting a separable quotient, you want to require the subspace $M$ of $X$ to not only be a proper subspace but of infinite codimension.  Otherwise that question is trivial. 

Comment: That's the 'Separable Quotient Problem'...

Comment: dear Andreas
you are right, I just got it by looking at the Ady idea. Thanks

Comment: @Yemon : My question is the question #1 in my post.

Comment: Steven, Ady has already mentioned that Question 1 in your current post is the Separable Quotient Problem; the answer is unknown but it is known to be yes for certain classes of Banach spaces. For a survey detailing the partial results known in the mid-1990s, see Mujica's survey *Separable quotients of Banach spaces*, Rev. Mat. Univ. Complutense Madrid 10 (1997), 299–330. A more recent result, that every Banach space isomorphic to a dual space has a separable quotient, has been shown my Argyros et al in *Unconditional families in Banach spaces*, Math. Ann. (2008) 341:15–38.

Comment: After posting my comment above I noticed that you say normed space rather than Banach space; do you mean Banach space?

Comment: Just as I was posting my comment Bill posted his answer (which contains more info than my comment, however maybe the survey article interests you; find it at http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol10-2/vol10-2e.pdf )

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing the title, which in its original form had the very easy answer "yes", and was apparently not at all what the OP meant to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your question is the famous "separable quotient problem", as Ady mentioned. From here on, "space" means "infinite dimensional Banach space".  A space $X$ has a separable quotient provided $X^*$ has a reflexive subspace (obvious), a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$ (Rosenthal and me), or $\ell_1$ (Hagler and me).  A result of PANDELIS DODOS, JORDI LOPEZ-ABAD and STEVO TODORCEVIC is that it is consistent with ZFC that if $X$ has density character at least $\aleph_\omega$ then $X$ has a separable quotient; see

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1860.pdf

Every dual space has a separable quotient (Argyros, Dodos, Kanellopoulos):

http://users.uoa.gr/~pdodos/Publications/13-Unconditional.pdf

There are other striking things that I can't locate quickly.

Every non reflexive quotient of a $C(K)$ space contains a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$ (classical result of Pelczynski), so $\ell_1$ is not a quotient of $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: Small comment regarding the last part: would it be very slightly quicker to note that if a Banach space quotients onto $\ell_1$ then it has a complemented subspace isomorphic to $\ell_1$ (and then use Pelczynski's result about complemented subspaces of $\ell_\infty$)?

Comment: It's the same proof, Yemon.  Pelczynski proved that every non weakly compact operator from a $C(K)$ space preserves a copy of $c_0$. I don't think his proof simplifies if the operator is a projection (though I could be wrong about that). 

Quite a bit later Lindenstrauss proved (using Pelczynski's theorem, BTW) that every complemented subspace of $\ell_\infty$ is isomorphic to $\ell_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the details Bill - as you have probably guessed, in my comment I meant Lindenstrauss when I said Pelczynski, and I was unaware that his proof used the result of Pelczynski which you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Here seems to be another reference paper from Jorge MUJICA, who transfer this seperable quotient space problem to some other equivalent problems.

http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol10-2/vol10-2e.pdf